# Is it possible to apply the kernel trick to a "mahalnobis distance learner" such as GLS?

Tags: kernel-trick, linear-algebra, generalized-least-squares, mahalanobis

1.https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.1441.pdf

2.https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925231210001165

These papers describe kernelizing a mahalanobis distance learner.

I am interested in formulating generalized least-squares as a kernel machine.

Wikipedia:$\hat{\beta}=\left(\mathbf{X}^{\top} \boldsymbol{\Omega}^{-1} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\top} \boldsymbol{\Omega}^{-1} \mathbf{y}$

Comment: The Mahalanobis distance is simply the Euclidean distance in a transformed space; from this perspective you can transform your input data according to a square root of $\Omega^{-1}$ and proceed with normal kernel methods on that space. (i.e. with $\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\gets\mathbf{L}\mathbf{X}$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{y}}\gets\mathbf{L}\mathbf{y}$ where $\mathbf{L}$ is, say, the Cholesky of $\Omega^{-1}$)

Comment: An alternative view is one where we perform no transformations, but (assuming a distance based kernel) use the Mahalanobis Metric rather than the Euclidean one.